# How to store large amount of key value pairs efficently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm writing a ML project where I need to acquire huge number of positions and their final outcomes (game of checkers). Position is represented as tuple of 32 integers between 0 and 4 (included) f. e:

```
pos = (0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0)
```

for each position I want to store:

```
result = white_wins - black_wins
num_games # total number of games
```

Because total number of positions is enourmus (I'm not even sure if it is managable). Certainly It is bounded from above by sth arround 2.3 x 10^22 and in reality total number of diffrent (possible to occure in game) positions is a lot smaller maybe even sth order of magnitude of 10^19 or less. At one [site](https://www.wired.com/2007/07/the-game-of-che/) I found that there is 5 x 10^20 possible games (move orders) that game can take which would indicate that number of unique positions is drastically smaller, but I'm not sure if I used same set of rules etc.

It's worth noting that firstly game gets played and then based on move record each position is added in a loop.

From here I tried to different aproaches:

**1. Storing data in python dict as:**

```
dict = {pos1: [result1, num_games1], ...}
```

And adding each position with:

```
def add_pos(dict, pos, who_won): # who_won = 1 if white wins and -1 if black 0 if draw
    if pos in dict.keys():
        dict[pos][0] += who_won
        dict[pos][1] += 1
    else:
        dict[pos] = [who_won, 1]
```

Then storing it with pytorch to .pth file with:

```
torch.save(dict, f'saves/pos_dict.pth', pickle_protocol=HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

**2. Storing it in sqlite3 database**

Created with:

```
self.cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pos_table (
                            pos TEXT PRIMARY KEY ,
                            result INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            num_games INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            eval REAL NOT NULL );""")
```

Adding position:

```
def add_pos(cur, pos, who_won):
    pos_str = str(pos)
    cur.execute("SELECT rowid FROM pos_table WHERE pos=?;",(temp,))
    row = self.cur.fetchone()

    if row is None:
        tuple_to_insert = (pos_str, who_won, 1, who_won)
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO pos_table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", tuple_to_insert)
    else:
        cur.execute("""UPDATE pos_table 
                       SET result=result+(?),
                           num_games = num_games+1,
                           eval = result/CAST(num_games AS REAL)
                           WHERE pos LIKE ?;""", (who_won, pos_str))
```

**Main problems:**

in both cases I would gladly get rid off "is position already in db check" or somehow generalize it for f.e. merging to dictionaries but I wasn't able to come up with any alghorithm that would be faster.

Problem with first aproach is that although it's reasonably fast it eats up a lot of RAM, also saving and loading it to file gets painfully slow as number of unique positions gets around 5 000 000.

Only problem I find with SQL is that it gets really slow really fast (around 500 000 - 700 000 unique positions) which makes it borderline useless at 1 000 000 or more rows

**Fixes:**

Easy and probably necessary fix is to pick some features of position f.e. number of pawns, queens etc. and therefore reduce number of distinguishable positions.

I heard about shelves although rejected it as unlikely to solve my problem (did not tested it)

Therefore I have few questions:

1. Is there way to improve data-storage system in order to increase number of unique positions that can be stored?
2. Approximetly how many distiguishable positions (after reducing to set of features) I would be able to handle efficently? - it's very important that finding value associated with key does not take a lot of time
3. Is there way to improve "inserting alghorithm"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQLite, some tips to improve performance:

1. Since your primary key isn't an `INTEGER`, make it a [WITHOUT ROWID](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) table. This will reduce the number of lookups that have to be done in the database to retrieve the values associated with the key from 2 (First in an index to find the corresponding rowid, then in the table itself) to 1 (Directly looking up in the table).

```py
self.cur.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pos_table (
                            pos TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                            result INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            num_games INTEGER NOT NULL,
                            eval REAL NOT NULL ) WITHOUT ROWID;""")
```

2. Use [UPSERT](https://sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html) syntax to need only a single query to insert or update.

```py
def add_pos(cur, pos, who_won):
    pos_str = str(pos)
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO pos_table(pos, result, num_games, eval)
                   VALUES (?1, ?2, 1, ?2)
                   ON CONFLICT(pos) DO UPDATE
                   SET result = result + ?2,
                       num_games = num_games + 1,
                       eval = result/CAST(num_games AS REAL);""", (pos_str, who_won))
```

You can also store the position in a more compact form than a stringified tuple to save space, by using 3 bits per element in an array of bytes (A total of 12 bytes for 32 elements). The [bitstruct](https://pypi.org/project/bitstruct/3.8.0/) module makes this easy.

Change the type of the `pos` column to `BLOB`, and something like

```py
import bitstruct
# ...
# Pack the positions into bytes
pos_str = bitstruct.pack("u3" * len(pos), *pos)
# Unpack back into a tuple
pos_tuple = bitstruct.unpack("u3" * 32, pos_str)
```

---

A non-sqlite alternative that you might explore is the [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module, which provides persistent storage of key-value pairs:

```py
import shelve
shelfdb=shelve.open("positions")

def add_pos(shelf, pos, who_won)
    pos_str=str(pos)
    if pos_str in shelf:
        tmp = shelf[pos_str]
        tmp[0] += who_won
        tmp[1] += 1
        shelf[pos_str] = tmp
    else:
        shelf[pos_str] = [who_won, 1]

# Close before exiting!
shelfdb.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! for sure I'll try them.